# How can I solve my android login problems?

Tags: java, android

(My mother tongue is not English. Maybe this question has some wrong grammars.)

When I try to login my app, this app always return SUCCESS even I typed wrong password.

First, I created DB table(PERSON).
Second, I created the method(chkpPw) that checking PW.
Third, I use this method to two ways.

this is what I want result.
1. empty ID or empty PW => Please enter your ID or PW.
2. Wrong ID, Wrong PW or Right PW => Your ID is not exist.
3. Right ID, Wrong PW => Please check your PW.
4. Right ID, Right PW => Success

But now my app returned these.
1. empty ID or empty PW => Please enter your ID or PW.
2. Wrong ID, Wrong PW or Right PW => Your ID is not exist.
3. Right ID, Wrong PW => Success
4. Right ID, Right PW => Success

My SQL query finds ID what exist in DB, not considering pw even pw exists or not....T_T....

this is PERSON table's data:

```
personID | pId | pPw
1 | apple111 | 11111111
2 | banana222 | 22222222
3 | peache333 | 33333333
```

### DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String KEY_NAME = "pId";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "tryangleDB", null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String personSql = "CREATE TABLE PERSON (" +
            "personID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "pId TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "pPw TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "pName TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "pBirth TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "pEmail TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "pPhone TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "pProfile BLOB, " +
             "cDate TEXT, " +
            "dDate TEXT)";

    db.execSQL(personSql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion == DATABASE_VERSION) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PERSON");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}


// check same id exists when user registers
public boolean chkpId (String pId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from person where pId=?", new String[]{pId});
    if (cursor.getCount()==0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

// when user tries to login, check pw with id
// ★Please help this part.
public boolean chkpPw (String pPw, String pId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select ? from person where pId= ?", new String[]{pPw, pId});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


//    // this is what I tried.
//    public boolean chkpPw(String pPw, String pId) {
//        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
//        String[] columns = {pPw, };
//        String[] parms = {pId };
//
//        Cursor cursor = db.query(" PERSON ", columns, "pId = ?", parms, null, null, null);
//        try {
//            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
//                return true;
//                // 트루라는 자체가 일치하는 id를 찾았다는 것

//            } else {
//                return false;
//            }
//        } catch (Exception e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//            return false;
//        } finally {
//
//        }
//    }
}
```

### LoginActivity.java

```
// skip upper part
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pPw = etPw.getText().toString();
                pId = etId.getText().toString();
//                boolean chkpId = db.chkpId(pId);
                boolean chkpPw = db.chkpPw(pPw, pId);

                // 1
                if (pId.equals("") || pPw.equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter your ID or PW.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                    try{//★ I think this part has some problems.



if (chkpPw) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else if (!chkpPw) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }





// ★ these are what I tried
//                        if(chkpPw==false) {
//                            save();
//                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//                            startActivity(intent);
//                        }

//                        if(chkpId==false&&(chkpPw==true||chkpPw==false)) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not exist ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }
//
//                        if(chkpId==true&&chkpPw==false) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"wrong PW",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }
//                        if(chkpPw==true) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not matched PW to this ID",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }

//                        if(chkpId==false && chkpPw==false) {
//                            save();
//                            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
//                            startActivity(intent);
//                        }

//                        else if (chkpId==false && chkpPw==true) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"not matched to PW",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }

//                        else if (chkpId==true && chkpPw==true) {
//                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please register.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } finally {
    //                        save();
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking if the id & password exists separately. A more appropriate approach would be to first check if id exists, then if **both** id & password exist. You'll probably want to do something along the following lines.

```
public boolean chkpPw (String pPw, String pId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select * from person where pPw=? and pId=?", new String[]{pPw, pId});
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Key point was WHERE pPw=? AND pId=?. I just tried to find right pid. All peple knew this except me. hahaha

Comment: Cool, upvote if it helped and mark the answer as correct if it worked. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Change the query in your `chkpPw` method to

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT 1 FROM `person` WHERE `pPw`=? AND `pId`=?", new String[]{pPw, pId});
```

Comment: Perfect answer!!! Key point was WHERE `pPw`=? AND `pId`=?....I just tried to find right pid. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

Your db chkpPw method I think is wrong. What you are doing is: select password when this user exists. As you may notice, this query will return at least one row if only id exists, so you return true and method says you is right.

Ok, now let's go through the answer.

For checking if user and password are right, you can try, according to your code, this:

select * from your_table where id=? and password=?

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't think SQL was wrong at all. But key point was WHERE pPw=? AND pId=?.